# Show that $\tau_A$ is a topology on $A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$. Let      $\tau_A$={$A \cap U: U \in \tau$}. Show that $\tau_A$ is a topology on $A$.

I know that I need to prove three properties to prove that $\tau$ is a topology, however, I don't know how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? "Follow your nose" proofs directly from definitions work for all the properties you need.

Comment: I don't know how to prove them. Just know what they are. For the first I was thinking that the null set and $A$ would belong to the topology as the topology is defined as an intersection between $A$ and an open set $U$. Is that right?

Comment: $\emptyset\in\tau$ by definition, so $\emptyset=\emptyset\cap A\in\tau_A$

Comment: Exactly. Don't forget that you can use the fact that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$.

Comment: @MikeHaskel How do I prove the other two properties though? I can't just assume any open set and prove that it's union and intersection is in the topology. Or can I?

Answer (score 1):

By definition $\varnothing,X\in\tau$, so $\varnothing = \varnothing\cap A\in\tau_A$ and $A=X\cap A\in\tau_A$.

If $U\cap A, V\cap A\in\tau_A$, then $U\cap V\in\tau$ so
$$(U\cap A)\cap(V\cap A) = (U\cap V)\cap A\in\tau_A. $$
If $U_\alpha\cap A\in\tau$ then $\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha\in\tau$ so
$$\bigcup_\alpha (U_\alpha\cap A) = \left(\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha\right) \cap A\in\tau_A. $$
Hence, $\tau_A$ is a topology on $A$ (called the **subspace topology**).

Comment: How do I prove intersection?

Comment: Do you mean, why does $(U\cap A)\cap(V\cap A) = (U\cap V)\cap A$? This is a straightforward exercise, just show that the sets are equal if you aren't convinced.

Comment: No, I mean that to prove topology we have to prove that the union and intersection of an arbitrary collection of open sets is in the topology right? You've proven the union? The same thing needs to be done for the intersection?

Comment: That is precisely what I proved.

Comment: Ok, so a similar thing needs to be done for the intersection? I just assume two sets and take it from there?

Comment: For exercises like these you just need to write down the definitions and see exactly what it is you need to show. It really isn't that difficult - it follows directly from the definition of a topology and some basic set theory.